# Post Mongoose 6, when do I still need to use markModified?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm updating our package dependencies and moving from Mongoose 5.x to 8.x. In the docs for migrating from 5 to 6, there's this note about not needing `markModified`:

> Mongoose arrays are now ES6 proxies. You no longer need to markModified() after setting an array index directly.

Source: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#arrays-are-proxies

However, in the docs for Mongoose 8, there is still a reference to markModified: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.markModified()

It's not entirely clear to me which scenarios are safe to remove `markModified` and which are not. Is it safe to remove all references, or is it preferable to just retain all our `markModified` lines if they no longer have an effect?

Answer (score 0):

This one is murky. How I remember it:

1. The version key is only updated when arrays change.
2. The version key is only updated when you use `document.save()`. Methods like `Model.findOneAndUpdate()` or `Model.findByIdAndUpdate()` etc won't update the version key when the array changes.
3. You **don't** need `markModified()`. If you are modifying an array field with either:

```js
document.arrayField.push('added');
document.arrayField.pull('removed');
```

4. You **do** need `markModified()` if you set the array element using square bracket notation:

```js
document.arrayField[0] = 'something changed';
```

Point 4 is contrary to what the [v5 -> v6 migration docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#arrays-are-proxies) say but is true in v7 and v8.