# Mongoose didn't automatic inscrease __v (mongoose version 6.2.7)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs, backend, mongoose-auto-increment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQEgf.png)

tried solution but not work for me
details : mongoose version 6.2.7
using updateOne function to update data.

need to working __v auto increment whenever updating the mongoose document.
need solution to automatically increase the __v in mongoose in nest js application.

Comment: The `__v` property is only modified when changes have been made to an array within the document, even then only using specific methods. You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77656166/21972629) useful.